# iOS: Accessibility for UICollectionView not working properly

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, accessibility, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having a UICollectionView and I've implemented accessibility for it.
Sometimes the voiceover speaks the UICollectionViewCell as "Cell number x, heading"; whereas I'm not putting the trait anywhere as .header.
Has anyone faced this issue? 
Added the code snippet for reference.

```
extension MyCollectionView {
    func setupAccessibility() {
        self.myCollectionView.disableAccessibility()
        self.menter code hereyCollectionView.shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren = true
    }
}

extension MyCollectionViewCell {
    func setupAccessibility(with index: Int) {
        isAccessibilityElement = true
        self.setAccessibility(label: "Cell number \(index)")
    }
}
```